# WooCommerce change My Account page slug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, slug

I want to change the address of My Account page.
It says right now `my-account` after Website URL.
i.e.

```
Website URL/my-account
```

I want to make it myaccount
For e.g

```
website URl/myaccount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do the same,

1) You can change the slug from `WP-Admin->Pages->My Account` page.

2) By defining custom rewrite rule,

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%myaccount%', 'my-account');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Comment: The first of these methods doesn’t work for me, editing to any value but "my-account" results in being unable to log in.